# Saving index values and results in a vector, list or data frame in triple for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have the following triple for loop in R :

```
res <- data.frame()

for (i in c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13)) {
  for (k in c(3,5,7,9,11,13)) {
    for (j in 1:41) {

      tmp <- chisq.test(matrix(c(counts[j,i],counts[j,(i+1)],counts[j,k],counts[j,(k+1)]),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))

      res<-c(res,c(tmp$p.value)) 
}}}
```

Where counts is a 14x41 data frame with genotype counts values (numbers like 600, 400, 240.. you can generate your own with random values in order to reproduce this in your computer).

And i want to save the resulting p.value of the chisq.test in a vector (res, from "results"). For now, the output is the following:

[image]

Which is OK, but now I also want it to have three more columns that indicate j,i and k values so then i can track where each p value came from, later. So, the desired output would be:

```
res
(p value 1) j1 i1 k1
(p value 2) j2 i2 k2
...
```

So, I modified the loop adding j,i,k to the final line, like this:

```
res <- data.frame()

for (i in c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13)) {
  for (k in c(3,5,7,9,11,13)) {
    for (j in 1:41) {

      tmp <- chisq.test(matrix(c(counts[j,i],counts[j,(i+1)],counts[j,k],counts[j,(k+1)]),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))

      res<-c(res,c(tmp$p.value,j,i,k)) 
}}}
```

And it produces the following result (which I don't like):

[image]

Any thoughts? thank you !

Comment: What is `counts`? Can you provide a reproducible example to run the code you'd provided?

Comment: It's explained on the question. "counts is a 14x41 data frame with genotype counts values (numbers like 600, 400, 240.. you can generate your own with random values in order to reproduce this in your computer).

"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new row to a dataframe instead of concatenating the results together.

Maybe something like this:

```
res <- NULL

for (i in c(1,3,5,7,9,11,13)) {
  for (k in c(3,5,7,9,11,13)) {
    for (j in 1:41) {

      tmp <- chisq.test(matrix(c(counts[j,i],counts[j,(i+1)],counts[j,k],counts[j,(k+1)]),nrow=2,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE))

      res<-rbind(res, data.frame(p.value = tmp$p.value,
                                 i = i,
                                 j = j,
                                 k = k, 
                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) 
    }}}
```

---

Data:

```
counts <- matrix(data = sample(1:1000, 574, replace = FALSE),
             nrow = 41, ncol = 14)
```

Comment: Excellent, you did it ! Thank you very much :D